# Django models - is it a good practice to create models that only link two tables?

Tags: python, django, orm

Let's say that I want to develop a simple todo-list app. This is what the `models.py` mght look like.

```
PRIORITIES = ["LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH", "URGENT"]

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Task(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    dueDate = models.DateField()
    priority = models.CharField(choices = PRIORITIES, default = "LOW")

class UserTask(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Here, the UserTask model was created only with a view to reducing redundancies in the database.

Is it a good practice? I don't think that this is what models should be used for.

Comment: Unless it contains other attributes, this is typically done with a `ManyToManyField`. In order to create such relation, Django indeed constructs such table.

Comment: But here it looks like a `Task` already *has* a reference to the `User`?

Comment: I'm sorry, this shouldn't have happened. Fixed:)

Comment: I read about ManyToMany, the problem is that this relation in question is in fact OneToMany.

Comment: butstill it is not clear to me: how are `User` and `Task` related? Is this a 1-to-many relation, a many-to-many? Some other quantifiers?

Comment: @LaTeXEnthousiast: then you should kee the `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here, the `UserTask` model was created only with a view to reducing redundancies in the database.

Given I understand it correctly, a `Task` belongs to a *single* `User`, at least based on your comment:

> I read about ManyToMany, the problem is that this relation in question is in fact OneToMany.

In that case, I do not see how you are "reducing" redundancies in the database, in fact you create *extra data duplication*, since now you need to keep the `Task` and its `user = ForeignKey(..)` in *harmony* with `UserTask`, this thus means that all creates, edits and removals have impact, and some circumvent Django's signal tooling, so it makes it quite hard, if not impossible.

The fact is that you do not *need* to construct a table to query the relation in reverse. By default Django will put a database *index* on a `ForeignKey`, so the database can efficiently retrieve the `Task`s that belong to a single (or multiple) users, it thus makes a `JOIN` with the `user` table more efficient.

One typically thus defines a `ForeignKey` like:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    dueDate = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.CharField(choices = PRIORITIES, default = "LOW")
```

At the Python/Django level, Django also provides convenience to obtain the tasks of a `User`. If you want to retrieve all the `Task`s of `some_user`, you can query with:

```
some_user.task_set.all()
```

or you can filter on the tasks, like:

```
some_user.task_set.filter(text__icontains='someword')
```

You can make the name of the relation in reverse more convenient as well, by specifying a `related_name` in the `ForeignKey`, like:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tasks'
    )
    text = models.TextField()
    dueDate = models.DateField()
    priority = models.CharField(choices = PRIORITIES, default = "LOW")
```

In which case you thus query the `Task`s of a `User` with:

```
some_user.tasks.all()
```

There is however a scenario where Django creates an implicit model that links two models together: in case one defines a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), since specifying an array of identifiers is typically hard (or even impossible) for a lot of relational databases (even if it is possible, typically one can no longer guarantee `FOREIGN KEY` constraints), etc.

In case the many-to-many relation between two models contains extra data (for example a timestamp when two users became friends), then one even defines an explicit model with two `ForeignKey` relations (and extra attributes), and uses this as a [**`through`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) model.